# How to drop files on Device in App Sandbox for Testing?

Tags: iphone, ipad, file, sandbox, nsfilemanager

I want to drop some files in my application's sandbox on the device for testing. Using iTunes to try to find the sandbox has not helped.

How do I browse to `/var/mobile/Applications/{My App UUID}/Documents` so I can drop some files for testing?

Answer (score 1):

On the simulator you will find the document directory for your application in:

```
/Users/.../Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications//Documents
```

And programmatically you can access that folder with these lines:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            NSDocumentDirectory, 
            NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString* docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you need to drop the files on the phisical device, you can use [DiskAid](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.digidna.net%2Fproducts%2Fdiskaid&ei=ED12TdzQMcfvsgbgprn7BA&usg=AFQjCNFqV8BjHQNC4zjU6_iSVq42HThEKg&sig2=IBjuB37ND01wyqKcj39HfQ)